# redundant 'update is available' message MFP version 8

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am getting 'update is available' message from MFP after installing a new build via TestFlight. This only happen the first time.

This my steps

1. Build by app with cordova build command
2. Open Xcode and add the Push entitlement and deploy to the TestFlight
3. execute the mfpdev webupdate command

After installing the update from TestFlight I get the 'Web update is available' message from MFP..

I have not change any html,css since I deploy to TestFlight. So, I am not sure why the update message

All I am changing in step 1 is  build# "android-versionCode" and "ios-CFBundleVersion"

I am using MFP V8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct Update is based on checksums. A checksum value is stored in the client whenever it is built. This checksum value is sent to the server as part of calls made to the server and is being compared to the client checksum value that is also stored on the server.

When performing `mfpdev app webupdate`, if there are any web resources changes in the application since its last state, the checksum value on the server will change.

Thus, the next time an application with an older checksum value attempts to connect, the checksum values will not match and a Direct Update will trigger.

That said, a change of a bundle identifier happening in the config.xml file and I am not sure if changes to this file are supposed to affect the checksum. Also note that changes to this file cannot be "updated" or "reflected" in the application by using Direct Update either. If you change something in this file then are you very much supposed to re-build the application and potentially release it with a new version number to the App Store / Google Play Store.

That said #2, as a workaround, simply do not execute the `webupdate` command and your issue should be resolved.

I do encourage you though to open a PMR to see if changes to the config.xml should or should not affect Direct Update.